# How to make many Node.js requests (using request module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request

**Main purpose:** I'm trying to scrape data off of around 10,000 different pages using Node.js.

**Problem:** It scrapes through the first 500~1000 very fast and then turns into a turtle (its variable where it slows down) beyond that, and then eventually just seems stuck forever.

I'm using the `request` module in Node.js to make the requests I then use `cheerio` to start scraping,

This code replicates my problem:

```
var request = require('request');

var requestsCalledCounter = 0;
var requestsCompletedCounter = 0;
var MAX_REQUESTS = 500;

var start = function () {
    while (requestsCalledCounter < MAX_REQUESTS) {
        request("http://www.google.com", function (error, response, html) {
            requestsCompletedCounter++;
        });
        requestsCalledCounter++;
    }
};

start();
```

**Output:**

Test 1:

> 447/500
>   89.4%
>
> Timed out: No requests completed after 5 seconds
>   447 Completed

Test 2:

> 427/500
>   85.39999999999999%
>
> Timed out: No requests completed after 5 seconds
>   427

**Extra details that might help:**

I have an array of URL's that I am going to scrape, so I am looping through them making a request to every URL in the array. It has about 10,000 URL's.

Comment: No wonder, you're making all the request simultaneously, that's expected behaviour. The `request` module won't scheduler them for you. Try waiting for requests to finish before moving on.

Comment: How do I wait? @cviejo

Comment: That's a broader question, how to handle asynchronous code. You can go with a number of patterns, using promises / generators, libs like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [asynquence](https://github.com/getify/asynquence), etc...In the simplest form, applied to your code: make the `while` loop around the request an `if` statement and call `start();` recursively from the request callback

Comment: Also i believe there's already a couple of node projects around that handle this scenario for you, you might want to take a look at one of those -don't ask me for links, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @cviejo in the comments. You should use an existing project. However to increase the understanding, here is an implementation that will only have 10 requests outstanding at a time.

```
var request = require('request');

var requestsCalledCounter = 0;
var requestsCompletedCounter = 0;
var pending = 0;
var MAX_PENDING = 10;
var MAX_REQUESTS = 500;

var doreq = function () {
    request("http://www.google.com", function (error, response, html) {
        requestsCompletedCounter++;
        pending--;
    });
    pending++;
    requestsCalledCounter++;
}

var start = function () {
    while (pending < MAX_PENDING && requestsCalledCounter < MAX_REQUESTS) {
        doreq();
    }
    if (requestsCalledCounter < MAX_REQUESTS) {
        setTimeout(start, 1);
    }
};

start();
```